# Prevent Android RecyclerView OnRemove shifting of remaining Items

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-animation

After removing an item from a recyclerview, by default, the other items shift up to fill the space of the removed element. How do I stop this movement?

I want to leave a gap in the view after I remove an item, instead of the other items moving up to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

How about not removing an item, but making its itemView invisible? You can just add two states to an object, that you use to bind ViewHolder, check this state in onBindViewHolder method and set visibility of an itemView with any animation you need. Something like this:

```
public class RecyclerViewItem {
    public boolean isVisible;
}
```

Set required state in your Activity/Fragment:

```
private void removeItem(int position){
    adapter.getDataSet().get(position).isVisible = false;
    adapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
}
```

And in your RecyclerView.Adapter:

```
private ArrayList<RecyclerViewItem> mDataSet;

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    RecyclerViewItem item = mDataSet.get(position);
    holder.itemView.setVisibility(item.isVisible? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
}
```